# howto call two ajax requests?

Tags: jquery, ajax

hi i have a problem with jquery and ajax,
i want to run the following script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    ajax_label();
    ajax_table();
});
```

and ajax_table and ajax_lable looks like:

```
function ajax_table() {
    $.get('myurl.php', function (data) {
        $('#foo').html(data);
    });
}
```

the problem is, when i run both ajax_table and ajax_lable it dont works.
when i just run one of the script like:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    ajax_label();
});
```

everything is fine. why it dotn works with both?

Comment: It'd be great if you could show the code for `ajax_label()` as well.

Comment: its nearly the same like ajax_table()

Comment: Perhaps a race condition? You know that they execute asynchronously?

Comment: Do you get any JS error? It should be no problem so its maybe a syntax error.

Comment: Sure, but show it anyway, please. Are you updating the same element perhaps? Are the elements they are updating nested? Also, "it doesn't work" how? Error messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might want to chain it:

```
function ajax_table() {
    $.get('myurl.php', function (data) {
        $('#foo').html(data);
        //when finished, load another
        ajax_label();
    });
}
```

Comment: or, you might want to set ajax to $.ajaxSetup({async:false});

Comment: However, async:false is bad because it blocks the UI

Comment: Dispite the fact that we have little knowledge about the logic he wants to achive... n_n

Comment: Indeed, that's what "Loading..." texts and animations are for... n_n

Comment: You wont get animation if UI is blocked :P And I meant lack of information provided.